# .MSG Files opens incorrectly on Shared drive

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When our users save emails on a network shared folder and later on try to open the file saved then it opens the file but the incorrect email.

E.g. Email gets saved on server as an .msg file named Printer but when opening the file it shows an entirely different .msg file with a different subject line

Comment: Have you looked at the `.msg` file using a text-editor to verify that it contains in fact what it should contain? Your user could have made an error while saving.

Comment: I've picked up when she saves the file it shows correctly but after a few days the file name stays the same but the content in it is different

Answer (score 0):

If the file is correct to start with, but its contents may change after a few days,
then somebody else is over-writing it with different contents.

If you don't want this to happen, set up more restrictive permissions on the file.
You might allow Read to everyone, but more than that only to some restricted user
accounts.